# ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have following code in my view

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mySelect").on('change',  function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'list-of-product-one',
          type: "get",
          data: {'id':$(this).val()},
          success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
    });        

<select class="form-control"  id="mySelect" name="cat_id" >             
   @foreach($category_list as $data)
      <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->cat_name}}</option>
   @endforeach 
</select>
```

and in my controller

```
public function ProductListGet(Request $request)
{
    $category_list=Category::all();
    $list_of_product=Product::where('cat_name','=',$request->id)->get();
    return view('manager/list_of_product',['list_of_product'=>$list_of_product,'category_list'=>$category_list]);
}
```

if I run that then it throws an error in my web browser console like

```
GET XHR http://localhost/poet/public/manager/list-of-product-one [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 156ms]
```

so I changed return in my controller like

```
 return json_encode($list_of_product);
```

then it displays the json array in my console even if return without

```
 $list_of_product=Product::where('cat_name','=',$request->id)->get();
```

this condition then it will return whole page

now my question is suppose if I have condition in my controller then how can I return my view ?

Comment: Have you tried  to load the page in browser to see if there are any errors? When I get 500 I usually have an error in the code

Comment: $,ajax never send $_POST['id'], $_GET['id'] it send $_POST['data'], $_GET['id']

Comment: @vision try reuqest->get('data')

Comment: @vision sorry, what i meant is it send data array

Comment: @Rajlaksh.i think its not an issue because if return json decode then it will diplay data

Comment: try this http://kopy.io/lZeGh

Comment: I found out  that return view needs to call render method in order to get html of  view.  return view('product')->render()

Comment: @Rajlaksh not working

Comment: @m_pro_m. not working

Comment: return view('manager/list_of_product')->with(['list_of_product'=>$list_of_product,'category_list'=>$category_list]);

Comment: Return it as json with that code I posted

Comment: return Response::json($data);

Comment: @Rajlaksh.return json working but not view

Comment: Response json return json so view not needed. view is not needed in your case.

Comment: return Json will return json why are you're trying to send json to view to display it?

Comment: Vision just do it like I said : return json that has the rendered view

Answer (score 1):

> GET XHR http://localhost/poet/public/manager/list-of-product-one [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 156ms]

Looks like you forgot send the _token. Add the following meta tag into the header section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Now, send the token into the ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     // here you prepare the token
     $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

     $("#mySelect").on('change',  function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'list-of-product-one',
          type: "get",
          data: {'id':$(this).val()},
          success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
     }
});
```

> this condition then it will return whole page

In other hand, you should check your view content because the use of `@extends('layout')` makes return the content of the entire template. Just put html's markup as simple without extending the template.